# Geany doesn't find javac

Tags: 14.04, java, geany

I'm attempting to compile a Java program using Geany.  I get `/bin/sh: 1: javac: not found` in the Compiler window.  The available help out there suggests to make sure you have OpenJDK installed, which I do (6 & 7). Poking around, I find `javac` in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`.  (I'm hesitant to start messing around with Java on Ubuntu since it seems to be so tempermental.)  **How do I point Geany to my Java installation?**  Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: what are the outputs of `which javac` and `update-alternatives --list javac`?

Comment: `which javac` returns nothing; `update-alternatives --list javac` returns `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javac`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Answer (score 5):

Try fixing the issue by installing Oracle JDK 8.
And try to find the correct version for the time being.
Before this remove the Default Open-JDK-"version"(your Version)
And try this code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I’d rather like to add a comment, but I don’t have the necessary reputation of 50, only 36. Here’s my annotation:

In 2021, you must write the command as follows:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

(openjdk-8-jdk instead of openjdk-7-jdk)

Comment: You can suggest an edit, if all this is a version change: https://askubuntu.com/posts/510983/edit